# how to use aiohttp with sever name indication?

Tags: python, ssl, sni

i have this simple usage of aiohhtp:

```
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile="some_cert")
        async with session.ws_connect(server_url, ssl=ssl_context) as ws:
            # Do something
```

But i want to connect to a domain that requires sni hostname.
im assuming this field should be added somewhere inside the ssl_context creation, but cannot find exactly where, and how.